# Replace "red-cross" in DataGridViewImageColumn of "new-row" with custom image

Tags: c#, image, winforms, datagridview

If you specify `AllowUserToAddRows` in a winforms `DataGridView` the user can add new rows manually in the grid. Now i want to add an image-button in one column which should be shown also in the new-row. But i cannot get it to show the image, only the red-cross image is shown like as if it wasn't found.

Here's a screenshot of the grid with the annoying image:

[image]

The image i want to show is in `Properties.Resources.Assign_OneToMany`.

I have searched everywhere and tried several ways like (in constructor):

```
var assignChargeColumn = (DataGridViewImageColumn)this.GrdChargeArrivalPart.Columns["AssignCharge"];
assignChargeColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
assignChargeColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = Properties.Resources.Assign_OneToMany;
```

or

```
private void GrdChargeArrivalPart_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    DataGridViewRow row = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    if (row.IsNewRow)
    {
        var imageCell = (DataGridViewImageCell) row.Cells["AssignCharge"];
        imageCell.Value = new Bitmap(1, 1);  // or ...:
        imageCell.Value = Properties.Resources.Assign_OneToMany; // or ...:
        imageCell.Value = null;
    }
}
```

Of course i have also assigned this image in the column-collection of the `DataGridView` on the designer:

[image]

So what is the right way to specify a default image for a `DataGridViewImageColumn` which is shown even if there is no data but only the new-row? If that matters, this is the jpg-image: [image]

Comment: What do you mean *new row*? Someone adds a new row. Then adds another one. Which is the new row. The current or both(current and previous)?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε: the `DataGridViewRow` which is added automatically if `AllowUserToAddRows` was set to `true`. It's the only row which returns `true` for [`IsNewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow(v=vs.110).aspx)(link inside, from MSDN: _"a row stops being the new row when data entry into the row begins."_). The user should be able to insert records by providing all values directly in the `DataGridView`. So basically this row replaces the form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can act in the `CellFormatting` event:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // ToDo: insert your own column index magic number 
    if (this.dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow && e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        e.Value = Properties.Resources.Assign_OneToMany;
    }

}
```

[image]

I believe it is ignoring your Image property assignment in the columns editor because that *row* is Nothing/Null to start with.

Comment: Wow, that works already. Let me have a look at the other answer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Draw the image manually because the system draws the default one:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.RowIndex >= 0) //change 3 with your collumn index
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

            if (dataGridView1 .Rows [e.RowIndex].IsNewRow )
            {
               Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.myImage;

               e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, e.CellBounds.Left + e.CellBounds.Width / 2 -  
                 bmp.Width / 2, e.CellBounds.Top + e.CellBounds.Height / 2 -  
                 bmp.Height / 2, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
             }

             e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This  never enters the inner `if` which checks `IsNewRow`. I also don't like to draw my images manually. However, thank you very much for your efforts(+1).