# Image Displaying a Red "X" in a DataGridView when loading from Resources

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

Im Trying to add a Image column From My Project's Resources to a newly created DataGridView
This Is the Code:

```
DataGridViewImageColumn myImage = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
myImage.Image = Properties.Resources.bullet_arrow_down;
myImage.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
myImage.Name = "Remove";
DirectoryGrid.Columns.Add(myImage);
```

But When i run the code i get the default "X" Image and not my selected image.
Is the Image Over Sized?(it's a 32x32 ico)
Must i add some bit conversion to it?

Most Code Online Wants you to load a image from a file,but i think that is messy.But if i have to so be it.But i found some references to indicate that this code should work fine.

Please note this image is used in another button and its working fine.
And i have tried other images as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have will work for rows that are added via `DataGridView.DataSource`. However, as you've seen, the `NewRow` still displays a red `x`.  This could be solved as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26124522/3773066).  However, once you've edited a cell of the `NewRow` and another one is added, the editing row no longer has your image, but is back to the red `x`.

**Solution**

Instead of handling the `CellFormatting` event, handle `DataGridView.RowsAdded`:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("ImageColumnName"))
  {
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ImageColumnName"].Value = Properties.Resources.MySavedImage;
  }
}
```

However, this won't catch the very first `NewRow` added because it is added once the first column is added to the `DataGridView`. So unless that first column *is* your image column, you'll also need to do the following:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(myImageColumn);
this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex].Cells["ImageColumnName"].Value = Properties.Resources.MySavedImage;
```

Comment: Thank You, I did not know the underlying cause of the problem. And now i do. In My case It was fine to disable User Input (The New Line) On the Context menu of the DatagridView.I'm using the Image to trigger a Remove Row function...