# red cross instead of bitmap displayed in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Good day,

I'm trying to display a bitmap in a column of a datagridview. I have tried several solutions but so far no one is really satisfactory. Before seeking help on stackoverflow.com, my last trial was the following :

In the form_load I wrote the following :

```
DataGridViewImageColumn l_Column = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
l_Column.Name = "Country_flag";
this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.Columns.Add(l_Column);
```

Afterwards I have added another function which does the following :

```
private void displayMeteoCities()
{
   DataTable l_Table = null;
   ClsCountriesFactory l_Countries = null;
   Bitmap l_Flag = null;
   string l_Country = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            l_Countries = new ClsCountriesFactory();
            l_Countries.loadCountryFlags();

            this.m_Meteo_Cities = new ClsMeteoCitiesFactory();
            this.m_Meteo_Cities.getMeteoCities();
            l_Table = ClsDomoosManagerCore.CreateDataTable(this.m_Meteo_Cities.Meteo_Cities);
            this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.DataSource = l_Table;

            this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Moccasin;
            this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                l_Country = Convert.ToString(this.dgr_Meteo_Cities["iso_country", i].Value);
                l_Flag = l_Countries.Flags[l_Country];
                this.dgr_Meteo_Cities["Country_flag", i].Value = l_Flag;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ClsErrorManager.manageException(exc);
        }
        finally
        {
            l_Table = null;
            l_Flag = null;
        }
```

What I am getting at, is a red cross displayed instead of the country icon.

When I said that I tried several solutions, I also tried to add the column in my function displayMeteoCities instead of creating it when the form is loaded.

Is there a workaround to prevent this problem from occuring? Or am I doing something drastically wrong?

Comment: Red cross usually means that the icon/image is not being found.

Comment: Thanks . the path is correct and the image does exist.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802160/image-displaying-a-red-x-in-a-datagridview-when-loading-from-resources) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122425/replace-red-cross-in-datagridviewimagecolumn-of-new-row-with-custom-image) may help you.